# Swagger sends this error: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource in Fastify NodeJS

Tags: node.js, swagger, fastify

I run Swagger to test my API that I wrote with NodeJS and the Fastify framework. Everything is ok and when I test my API in Postman everything is Ok. But in Swagger I get this error:

```
TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
```

After I search about it I found that I should add CORN to my code. So I wrote this code in server.js:

```
fastify.addHook('onSend', (request, reply, payload, next) => {
  reply.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  reply.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Cache-Control')
  reply.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET')
  Object.assign(reply.res, {
    payload: JSON.parse(payload),
    input: request.body || request.query,
  })
  next()
})
```

But Swagger does not work with addHook! I don't know why! when I add this to my code and go to this url: localhost:3002/documentation to see my Swagger API i get this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse ()
```

But Swagger was ok when I commented addHook from my code and after that I get the first error!
How can i add CORN to my code whit out addHook?

Comment: https://github.com/fastify/fastify-cors

Comment: Have al look at this package that helps you to configure CORS on your fastify app

Comment: @dimagolovin I also tested it : fastify.register(require('fastify-cors'), { origin: '*' })
but i get same problem .. :(

Comment: You comment out the 'addHook' and use 'fastify-cors' and still getting 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse ()' ?

Comment: no no, in this situation get this error : **TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource** from swagger

Comment: Why run `Object.assign` inside the hooks? I think that could be the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `onSend` hook runs for every request in the same context.

So, when a client does a request to `http://localhost:3000/docs` the retuned `payload` is a text of `text/html`, not a JSON. Check the [fastify's lifecycle](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/master/docs/Lifecycle.md#lifecycle).

So running `JSON.parse(payload)` on a text or to an empty response will cause the error you get.

I should have more info to suggest a better approach since [fastify-cors](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-cors) should work (it add to the responses the same headers you are adding)
So I would change the hook code:

```js
fastify.addHook('onSend', (request, reply, payload, next) => {
  reply.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  reply.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Cache-Control')
  reply.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET')

  let parsed
  if (payload) {
    try { // try to parse
      parsed = JSON.parse(payload)
    } catch (error) {
      // pa
    }
  }
  Object.assign(reply.res, {
    payload: parsed,
    input: request.body || request.query
  })
  next()
})
```